# MySQL select group by having column != x

Tags: mysql, sql, select-query

I'm trying to select rows where a certain column does not have a certain value, such as 0, but I'm unable to get this to work.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM rentals
GROUP BY date, rooms, price 
HAVING show_independently < 1
```

If `show_independently` is 1, then I don't want to group them. However, this statement shows no rows even though most rows have `show_independently` as 0.

Comment: Don't you want a `WHERE` instead?

Comment: `If show_independently is 1, then I don't want to group them. ` Do you want to include *all* rows in the result, but group only those that meet a certain condition? Or do you only want to SELECT those that meet a condition and group those?

Comment: I want to include all rows, both show_independently = 0 and show_independently = 1, but I only want show_independently = 0 to be grouped. I need show_independently = 1 separated so I can still see them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to group *some rows* and leave others ungrouped, you can use a `UNION`:

```
SELECT *
FROM rentals
WHERE show_independently <> 1
GROUP BY date, rooms, price 
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM rentals
WHERE show_independently = 1
```

This groups only those where `show_independently` is not 1, and includes the rest without grouping them.

Comment: I think this is what I want.

Comment: Now I need to select room types by # of rooms based on the results... does this have to be a join on both selects?

Comment: @dhinged You best [**ask a new question**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) for that ;)

Answer (score 2):

```sql
SELECT date, rooms, price 
FROM rentals
WHERE show_independently < 1
GROUP BY date, rooms, price
```

Comment: That only selects rows that have show_independently = 0. I still need to select rows with show_independently = 1, just not grouped with the show_independently = 0 rows.

Answer (score 0):

A [`HAVING`](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-having.aspx) clause is used when you are using an aggregate function  to filter data.

A typical query with `HAVING`:

```sql
SELECT yourColumn, aggregate_function(otherColumn)
FROM yourTable
WHERE yourColumn = someValue
GROUP BY yourColumn
HAVING aggregate_function(otherColumn) = someOtherValue
```

I think you want to be using a `WHERE` clause:

```sql
SELECT date, rooms, price 
FROM rentals
WHERE show_independently < 1
GROUP BY date, rooms, price
```